# LG Washer not working

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

I have an LG WM2051HVA washing machine that I have been having issues with. When put on 
`Delicates` and `Rinse+Spin` it rinses and works fine until it gets to `Spinning`, when it stops spinning and, after a few minutes it says the `LE` error code. I have replaced the hall effect sensor, checked the wiring harness, and replaced the main control board. Any suggestions as to what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Code [LE](http://www.lg.com/us/support/product-help/CT10000010-20150140270078-other-error-codes?search=&categoryId=CT10000010&superCategoryId=CT10000005&symptom=&subsymptom=&sort=) for this (front load) washer is that the motor is locked... probably because the load is too heavy. If you have a top loading washer, the code might mean the drain  is clogged (specifically, LG says the area between the washplate and inner basket may have coins or paper clips).

From [LG's trouble shooting tips](http://www.lg.com/us/support/product-help/CT10000010-1337701712239):

An LE error code on the washer's display indicates that the motor is locked, possibly due to a heavy wash load.

Large and heavy sized loads will put a strain on the motor, causing the LE code to occur. Performing a reset on the washer will normally resolve this error.

To reset the washing machine:

1. Press **POWER** to turn the washer off Unplug the washer from the power outlet.
2. If the outlet cannot be reached, turn the circuit breaker to the unit off.
3. With the power disabled to the washer, press and holdthe START/PAUSE button for 5 seconds.
4. Plug the washer back in, or turn the circuit breaker back on.
5. The washer should now be reset and the LE code cleared.

   If washing a heavy or large load, reduce the load size and attempt to restart the cycle.

[image]

Comment: The washer is empty, and it is a front load, and it has been reset. Still no luck

Comment: Perhaps the code is CE or UE but the digit C or U looks like an L? UE is unbalbanced load. CE is an electrical current problem (there's a short or a ground fault).  Did you unplug the washer for 10 seconds? Also, in my humble experience, there is a drain filter hose wich collects pennies and lint. Check the drain screen for debris and the drain hose for kinks. I added a picture the answer showing where to locate the drain.